# Apache Storm 2.2.0 UI: No tuples are emitted nor transferred

Tags: tuples, apache-storm

I 'm using Apache Storm 2.2.0. My spout reads a json file, and emits it to a bolt which stores it to ES. My pom.xml has the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My `storm.yaml`:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
      - "localhost"
#     - "server1"
#     - "server2"
# 
 nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"]
# 
 storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
 nimbus.host: "127.0.0.1"
 storm.local.dir: "/tmp/storm-data"
 ui.port: 8082
 java.library.path: "/usr/local/lib"
 supervisor.slots.ports:
     - 6700
     - 6701
     - 6702
     - 6703
```

I submit my topology using the command:

```
storm jar --jar /home/john/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.jar,/home/john/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/7.6.1/elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.1.jar target/my-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar MyTopology
```

My topology is successfully submitted to Storm, as I can verify from Storm UI, however, I see no tuples emitted/transferred from my spout (and as a result from my bolt neither).

Using `LocalCluster` everything works fine and I can verify the tuples inserted into my ES index. Using

```
StormSubmitter.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME, conf, topology);
```

though, and submitting it with the above command, I see no errors neither (say, e.g., it couldn't find the input json file). I do see that the number of workers, of supervisors, of executors and of tasks are >0, but no tuples are emitted/transferred.

I run `storm nimbus` and `storm supervisor` in the same machine. Do I need to start another supervisor in another machine for it to work? It should work with one supervisor only.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where would you expect what kind for output? Have you checked the `nimbus.log` and the supervisor log (workers-artifacts) for errors?

Comment: No errors in either of the log files 
`[INFO] Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)`.
What about these:
`org.apache.storm.utils.WrappedKeyNotFoundException: dep-gson-2.8.6-5e91b31c-e5a0-4c11-82a0-3ac8853694d8.jar
org.apache.storm.utils.WrappedKeyNotFoundException: dep-elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.1-8cde0252-4d2b-4179-b0ee-d94532744348.jar
Get topo conf exception. (topology id='es-index-flights-2-1624267077')
org.apache.storm.utils.WrappedNotAliveException: es-index-flights-2-1624267077`

Comment: `o.a.s.s.b.s.DefaultBlacklistStrategy timer [INFO] Need 2 slots more. Releasing some blacklisted nodes to cover it.

o.a.s.s.b.BlacklistScheduler timer [INFO] Supervisors [] are blacklisted.
o.a.s.s.EvenScheduler timer [INFO] Available slots: [f6ec5d6c-...-127.0.1.1:6702, f6ec5d6c-3fdb-...-127.0.1.1:6703]

o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus timer [INFO] Reassigning es-index-flights-1-1624467632 to 2 slots

o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus timer [INFO] Reassign executors: [[8, 8], [7, 7], [6, 6], [5, 5], [4, 4], [3, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1]]

o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus timer [INFO] Fragmentation after scheduling is:`